# Feed Electron's webview with HTML contained in a string

Tags: electron

I want to embed an "HTML viewer" inside of my Electron app, which would be fed with HTML contained in a string. My application automatically generates HTML code, which I want to visualize rendered as it would be displayed in a web browser.

I have seen there is a component called [`<webview>`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/webview-tag) but it loads the HTML content from an external site via URI.

Is it possible to feed this `<webview>` component (or any other) with HTML from a simple string to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this in electron repository
https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/1146

You can go with data uri, if you don't need JavaScript.

If you need JavaScript, there is a workaround.  You can save the html string as a html file and load the html file in electron

Once the window is closed,  you can delete the html file